# How to add insert svg(qr) to pdf file? Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, svg

i use RQRCode to create qr code and want after that insert my svg( not one a few ) in a pdf.
Can i do it with nokogiri? or how to do it?   Should i convert qr to xml and next insert this xml(qr) to xml(pdf-file) and after that convert xml to pdf?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [prawn-svg](https://github.com/mogest/prawn-svg) to directly embed the SVG into a PDF document generated by Prawn.

If that doesn't work for you, convert the SVG to an image format like PNG and then include that image.